# Wagtail: How can I display Categories from Child Pages on a List Page

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to get the hang of Wagtail and have a page that lists all of the posts on the site.

I want to display a category tab on the card that holds the info for each post.

The text and title are pulling correctly, but I can't get the category data.

I have this code, but it pulls every category on the site, not for each post.

```
              {% for cat in categories %}
                <li class="d-inline-flex">
                  <a href="{{self.get_parent.url}}?category={{cat.slug}}">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary pt-2 pb-2">{{cat.name}}</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
```

```
class LessonCategory(models.Model):
    """ Set Up Lesson Category In Wagtail Admin """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=40,
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode=True,
        help_text="Add a category slug",
        )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Page List Model

```
class LessonListPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    """ Lists all the lessons on one page """

    template = "lesson/lesson_list_page.html"

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context"""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["posts"] = LessonDetailPage.objects.live().public()
        #Change 'public' to adjust which posts are displayed
        context["categories"] = LessonCategory.objects.all()
        return context

    @route(r'^latest/$')
    def latest_lesson_posts(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # @todo Adjust the number of lessons that are displayed at one time
        context["latest_lessons"] = LessonDetailPage.objects.live().public()[:10]
        return render(request, "lesson/latest_lessons.html", context)
```

Comment: How is `categories` being passed into the view? It might be helpful to also add your `Page` model code. Maybe you could try `{% for cat in self.categories %}`.

Comment: I updated to add that info. I'm guessing it must be connected to how I'm passing in the category context.

Comment: How have you modelled the relationship between LessonCategory and LessonListPage ? in your get context method you are returning all LessonCategory objects not the related ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
              {% for cat in post.categories.all %}
                  <li class="d-inline-flex">
                    <a href="{{cat.get_parent.url}}?category={{cat.slug}}">
                      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary pt-2 pb-2"> 
                       {{cat.name}} 
                     </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
              {% endfor %}
```

Changing 'categories' -->  'post.categories.all' did the trick.